# Tracking Views on Webparts (by user)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reports, site-usage

I'm nearing completion on my organization's SharePoint site and was asked to find a way to show a report that indicates usage. Not just the simple view count report that is built-in, but rather a report that displays users and their view count/view date.

I am looking for both, entire page views and individual webpart views. Is there anyway to do this with the Out-of-the-Box platform? I'm not looking to spend additional money.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for both, entire page views and individual webpart views.
>   Is there anyway to do this with the Out-of-the-Box platform? I'm not
>   looking to spend additional money.

You can do it for free, only some JavaScript coding required,
no need for SharePoint Designer or Powershell or back-end code

#### JSLink

Since SP2013 you can add JSLinks to WebParts **and Views**

Basically they are just Javascript files that get executed when something is displayed.

Terms JSlink/CSR are used interchangeably, strictly speaking:

- a **CSR** (Client Side Redering) file: changes the HTML of SharePoint elements
- **JSLink**: when this WebPart/View/Form is displayed use CSR file

So JSLinks can point to **any** JavaScript code, don't have to be CSR code files!!
(*on SharePoint Online they can even point to any external file

 Theoretically I could now give you the URL of our 365CSI TrackerJS file and it would do anything you asked for (including creating the required List in your own Tenant) ... but this is code for clients and you did not want to spend anymore*

#### Counting View displays per User

- Create a List ViewCount with only default Columns: Title, Created, Created By
- Attach a JSLink to your Views
- The JSfile

  - (using JSOM or REST) Writes the View Title to the ViewCount Title column
    (*Created and Created By are set by default*)

The [Chrome Browser Extension Cisar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo) (by the One and Only JS-Wizard Andrei Markeev) makes creating a CSR file a breeze (but your code is not doing any Client Side Rendering...)

Only thing with Cisar, it adds the JSLink to the WebPart, NOT the View, which  won't make any difference for ListView Pages; only when you add a WebPart to an exiting ASPX page and re-use an existing View, you need to set the JSLink (on that **new** WebPart) by hand

Actually, you don't want to set the JSLink on the **View**... SharePoint ignores **any** View JSlinks when there is a JSLink set on the **WebPart**... So if any other (3rd party) code adds a JSLink on the **WebPart**... your precious View-JSLinks will NOT execute.

#### More CSR / JSLink blogs

- (dec 2015) - [Pitfalls using CSR/JSLink](https://www.scnsoft.com/blog/pitfalls-of-using-jslink-with-sharepoint-apps-for-office-store)
- (aug 2014) - [Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) - Andrei Markeev
- (aug 2014) - [Client Side Rendering: List Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms) - Andrei Markeev
- (jan 2016) - [CSR overrides in detail](http://josharepoint.com/2016/01/14/sharepoint-2013-client-side-rendering-register-templates-overrides-in-detail/) - José Quinto
- (aug 2013) - [JSLink and Display Templates](http://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-1.html) -Martin Hatch
- (dec 2012) - [SP 2013: Using the JSLink property to change the way your field or views are rendered in SharePoint 2013](https://zimmergren.net/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013) - Tobias Zimmergren
- (dec 2012) - [SP 2013: Measuring performance on the JSLink property in SharePoint 2013](https://zimmergren.net/sp-2013-measuring-performance-on-the-jslink-property-in-sharepoint-2013) - Tobias Zimmergren
- (jul 2013) - [5 facts about JSLink you might not know](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/5-facts-about-jslink-in-sharepoint-2013-you-might-not-know) - Anton Vishnyakov
- (may 2015) - [CSS registration & ScriptLink done the right way](http://yakovenkomax.com/cssregistration-and-scriptlink-done-the-right-way/) - Max Yokavenko

#### Support Tools

- BookMarklet [iCSR Link Manager](https://365csi.nl/icsr/linkmanager.html)
  update JSLink settings on WebParts & Views, deploy JS files to Style Library; and UserCustomActions Manager
- (Chrome Browser Extension) [Cisar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en)
  Edit CSR files with Live Updating
- (Chrome Browser Extension) [Chrome SP Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd/related?hl=en)
  Edit SharePoint files, add ScriptLinks to SiteCollection/Webs, manage Web Property Bag

#### One code file to rule them all.. even on SP210

UserCustomActions (available since SP2010) are very powerful, basically the same as adding a script file to the MasterPage: One JavaScript files gets executed on **every page**

So you can, *Big Brother*, Track everything you want...

#### ... not everything on Office365...

FYI, For now, The Office365 ***New Experiences*** (Document Library, List, site Contents) do **NOT** allow any custom code, no CSR, no UserCustomActions, no branding, no MasterPage, no... etc.

Be sure to check the Blogs after Microsoft Ignite conference (sept 26-30) on this topic

iJS iCSR